# MySql timestamp timezone weirdness

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to grab records from a table based on the day of the month the record was created.
This information is stored in a Unix timestamp.  During testing I created new test records and threw in some timestamps for specific times that I had converted to timestamps using an online converter.  I used...

```
01/29/2010-02:00:00
```

Right now I'm using...

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, '%d') == 29
```

This should work for all times on the 29th day of every month.  But it is calculating the timestamp to be 5 hours behind the actual value of the timestamp. When I just run a FROM_UNIXTIME on the timestamp it returns 01/28/2010-21:00:00.  I was hoping someone could give an explanation for this, if there is an easy fix or should I just code the program to expect the timezone to be a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FROM_UNIXTIME function automatically converts the datetime to the current timezone.